# How to perform variable/feature selection before random forest in R?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, correlation, random-forest

I have a phyloseq object with 4000+ taxa and 300+ samples.

What methods/packages can I use to perform feature selection to reduce the number of taxa/OTUs prior to performing random forest? I was hoping to check correlations between different taxa.

I'm planning to use the taxa as predictors of disease (i.e., disease~.).

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you hope to accomplish with variable selection?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.